# href anchor width stays at zero

Tags: html, css, image, width, href

I'm having a problem with my href anchor: I can't get it to show; its width stays at zero, so the image I put inside doesn't show and I cannot click. It works with text but not with my images; however they do show when I leave the href anchor out of my code, so the problem isn't with the image source.

I added *style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;"* to the anchor tag (I also tried setting a fixed width with width: 25px;), but the width of my anchor remains null...

Would some of you have any idea of how to fix that?

Thank you!

```css
.levels{
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.levels_rows{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.global{
    display: flex;
    width: 20%;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-right: 2%;
}

.other{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="levels">
  <div class="levels_rows">
    <div class="global">
      <p style="font-size:14px; font-weight:900; text-transform:uppercase; margin-bottom: 2%;">Title</p>
      <div class="other">
        <a style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;" href="#URL">
          here I have an image
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.global{
display: flex;
width: 100%;
flex-direction: column;
padding-right: 2%;
}

.other{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
width: 100%;
}
```

> i changed the width in the global and other class to 100% and the text is alligned. is this u are asking for?

Comment: Thank you for your time! Unfortunately nope, I don't care whether the text is aligned or not (I am using an image on my website, not some text, and with wdth: 100%, the images aren't displayed in the may I want them to be. The problem is that the href anchor tag's width stays equal to zero no matter what I try to do... :'(

Answer (score 0):

> I think i found it.

```css
.levels{
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.levels_rows{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.global{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-right: 2%;
}

.other{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="levels">
  <div class="levels_rows">
    <div class="global">
      <p style="font-size:14px; font-weight:900; text-transform:uppercase; margin-bottom: 2%;">Title</p>
      <div class="other">
        <a href="www.google.com" target = "_blank">
          <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/closeup-acrylic-paints-background_23-2148315460.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```